# iOS App Update Process using single app mode (SAM)

Tags: ios, swift, deployment, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We have an enterprise app that will run through our MDM in ASAM (Autonomous Single App Mode). We will install it through the MDM but need to be able to detect and initiate updates programatically without user interaction.

From the thread I gather this is possible for enterprise apps as long as they are not currently the front running app.

BTW all ipads will be managed and supervised so we have complete control of them.

We are following somewhat the plan laid out in comments above:

1) Have Single App Mode running on target app
2) Ping our server to identify a new update available (compare current version to listed version)
3) Disable Single App Mode on target app
4) Launch Maintenance App (just shows image saying "Maintenance Mode...Please Wait")
5) Push update to target app
6) Relaunch Target App
7) Re-enable Single App Mode on target app

The question I have is around Step 5 above.

Typically we would initiate the update through a browser to start the download and update of the application, however I need this instead to be initiated automatically, I would assume by the maintenance app.

How would I programatically initiate an update to an enterprise app without prompting the user to accept the update? Or is this something I have to push through the MDM and can't be called on from an app within the ipad?

Thanks in advance for your help.